# Intellij failed to run sample program and gives "Failed to get version of function(null)" when I run with Azure

Tags: azure, intellij-idea

So I am following a tutorial on how to use Azure and it wouldn't run locally. I've installed the Azure toolkit already and I have IntelliJ pointing to it (2nd picture), but it still doesn't work. I downloaded the latest version too. Does anyone know what is going on?

[Photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpD7d.png)

[Photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpca1.png)